# Is it possible to export functions that have bindings to names that are variables?

Tags: r, package

(Feel free to edit the confusing title)

Suppose I want to define three functions to point to the same function - I can achieve that with code like this

```
orig <- function() {
  match.call()[[1]]
}

one <- orig
two <- orig
three <- orig
```

If this is inside a package and I want to make the `one`, `two`, `three` functions "public", I can easily just add a roxygen `@export` above them:

```
orig <- function() {
  match.call()[[1]]
}

#' @export
one <- orig
#' @export
two <- orig
#' @export
three <- orig
```

But what if I want to store the function names in a vector such as `c("one", "two", "three")` and then define and export the functions based on that vector?

If I'm not in a package, I could use

```
methods <- c("one", "two", "three")
lapply(methods, function(x) assign(x, orig, envir = parent.env(environment())))
```

But as far as I can tell, I can't export functions that are created this way.

One potential usecase can be if I define a function and want to have many synonyms to it.  That's probably not a good idea, but for the sake of learning, I'd like to know if there's there a way to achieve this?

Comment: You should always make explicit assignments and definitions in packages, like how you did it at the top

Comment: I understand it'd be very bad form to do what I'm asking, but is it actually impossible? I'm not planning on actually using it anywhere, but I'm still curious

Comment: You may be able to still export them using the NAMESPACE file directive `export`.  Have you tried that?

Comment: I haven't - I've been relying solely on devtools to build, and I don't know how to build&load my package locally without devtools rewriting the NAMESPACE file.  I suppose the building process would be useful to know so maybe I should look into how to do this, thanks